# How to include and use jQuery in Aurelia using Aurelia CLI and Semantic UI in a right way?

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui, aurelia

We are working on a project using Aurelia, Aurelia CLI, jQuery and Semantic UI.

Currently, we have the following lines included in the head section of `index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.1/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

We have a navigation bar where one element is a drop-down menu offered by Semantic UI:

```
  <div id="navbar_account" class="ui dropdown item navbar text" if.bind="connector.loggedIn">
    Dropdown menu
    <i class="left dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <a class="item" click.delegate="">My account</a>
      <a class="item" click.delegate="">Logout</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In order to make it usable we are adding this code to corresponding js file:

```
  attached() {
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
  }
```

The problem is, this code doesn’t seem to work when the website or page is opened the first time. Only when we click on some other nav-bar link, then this drop-down menu starts to work.

It feels like, something is being activated not in the right order. Maybe we are importing jQuery not in a right way or we don’t active it correctly. Maybe it’s a problem with Semantic UI.

All my trials to add jQuery as a dependency or as a prepend to Aurelia CLI projector (`aurelia.json`) were not successful.

In one of the latest trials, I run:

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install github:components/jqueryui#1.12.1 --save
```

Added to `aurelia.json`:

```
        "prepend": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/components-jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js",
           ...
```

Added to `index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/components-jqueryui/themes/base/all.css">
```

With this steps, I made the Aurelia project not runnable anymore with `au run –watch`

```
{ Error: Cannot find module 'gulp'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Promise (D:\gitkraken\ad\aurelia\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\commands\gulp.js:19:20)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports.execute (D:\gitkraken\ad\aurelia\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\commands\gulp.js:18:12)
    at _establishProject.then.then (D:\gitkraken\ad\aurelia\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\cli.js:36:24)
    at <anonymous> code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you do this:

```
attached() {
  $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
}
```

You'll want to inject the `TaskQueue` component in that element and wrap this in a `queueMicroTask` call like so:

```
attached() {
  this.taskQueue.queueMicroTask(() => {
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
  });
}
```

This ensures everything is fully rendered before the jQuery call. It's generally the recommended way to integrate with 3rd party UI components.

As for the other problem: I'm surprised you get an error regarding gulp when you prepend jquery to your vendor bundle. These problems are hard to troubleshoot without seeing your **complete** aurelia.json (and possibly package.json).

#### Without jquery

And lastly, you may want to consider **not** using jQuery / jQuery UI or Semantic UI's javascript. I personally only use the CSS and build the component behaviors myself with Aurelia because Aurelia makes it so easy with delegates and bindings.

I can highly recommend you try it. It will make you better with HTML/CSS/JavaScript/Aurelia and you get higher quality projects + stuff you can reuse across projects. Plus never any need to drag in those problematic dependencies.

Example:

```
<div id="navbar_account" class="ui dropdown item navbar text">
  Dropdown menu
  <i class="left dropdown icon" click.delegate="showDropdown = !showDropdown"></i>
  <div class="menu" show.bind="showDropdown">
    <a class="item">My account</a>
    <a class="item">Logout</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And that's all there is to making something show/hide on click!

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Here are these 2 files:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/htceb2ah9x70zux/package.json?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/q5cavzm2uojybm2/aurelia.json?dl=0

Comment: @GeorgeP. Looks pretty standard to me. You should be able to add your jquery file right underneath bluebird in `prepend` without any problems. Have you tried the `queueMicroTask`?

Comment: My first impression is that queueMicroTask did the magic and solved the initial problem! I'll test it more in the next days. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: Unfortunately, queueMicroTask didn’t solve the problem, but I figured out, what is causing the problem. The whole dropdown is in a div element, which I’m showing depending on if the person is logged in or not. So I am using if.bind=”connector.isLoggedIn”, where a connector is injected class and isLoggedIn a boolean. At the point of activation of dropdown (attached()) the value for loggedIn is false. I think it activates the element, which doesn’t exist at that point. If I change if.bind to ”true”, the dropdown works fine.

Comment: Yes, I kind of eluded that with my example (I removed the `if.bind` for a good reason) but should have mentioned that explicitly instead. My bad. So to clarify: you should change `if.bind` to `show.bind`. `if.bind` completely removes the element from the DOM (thereby disconnecting all behavior on it) whereas `show.bind` simply hides it via CSS and it will still work.